# How to check if element is present before continuing using selenium and python?

Tags: python, html, selenium

How would I go about running a loop as long as a specific div-element is present on a website?

I need the parser to go through a number of pages and click *next* for each page - the last page is empty and thus lacks the aforementioned div-element, so I figured running this within a while-loop would be a good approach. I'm however not sure how I should make this properly.

What I currently have, though non-functioning, is:

```
test = driver.find_element_by_class_name("divClassName").size()
```

, and subsequently checking whether its size is `while(test != 0)`.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: could you show what you got so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Richy, my bad, I've updated my question a bit - hopefully with additional clarity. I initially did not want to include things as it is not working, but having read the page I've updated accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the update, but would be even better if you could show us still more. How does the loop look? Maybe the solution could be something like `while true: if not test: break`

Comment: The way I've approached this has been to first code the parsing for one page, subsequently going through each page. I've now taken all this - which works on its own - and placed it within the aforementioned while-loop to ensure it only runs till the last, empty page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement below approach:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException    

while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("divClassName")
        # do what you need
        # click "Next" button
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

With above code you'll be able to get new page and perform actions if `<div class="divClassName">` is found, and stops otherwise

Also note that `size` is a `property` of webelement, but not a `method`. You should use it as `webelement.size` instead of `webelement.size()`

Comment: This works -- thank you very much! Also thanks for the note on size, much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of while, is there a way to just test it only once or twice?

Comment: Use `for` loop instead of `while` loop. E.g. `for once in range(n): ...` will run loop `n` times